# Theos iOS 11 system() function

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios11, jailbreak, theos

I updated my Phone to IOS 11 and the system() function is not supported anymore. I want to shutdown after pressing a button, how can I do that? Respring works fine with posix_spawn. My old code is:

```
(void)shutdownButtonPressed{
    system("shutdown");
}
```

Comment: An app shouldn't be able to shut down the phone.  If this is a jailbreak specific question, tag it as such, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the `shutdown` source](https://opensource.apple.com/source/system_cmds/system_cmds-805.220.1/shutdown.tproj/shutdown.c.auto.html), it would seem the proper way of doing this is:

```
#define RB_HALT 0x08
extern void* reboot3(int how);

(void)shutdownButtonPressed {
    // for a real reboot, just pass 0 instead of RB_HALT
    reboot3(RB_HALT);
}
```