# How add reboot button to my tweak using THEOS

Tags: macos, jailbreak, reboot, theos

**Hi, I need help to add a reboot button in the preference bundle of my tweak.
I have this in my tweakRootListController.m**

`-(void)reboot {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] reboot];
    return;
}`

**But when i try to compile the project, it's return me an error**

`MacBook-Pro-de-Valentin:respringx valentincocq$ make package install
 Making all for bundle RespringX…
==> Copying resource directories into the bundle wrapper…
==> Compiling respringRootListController.m (arm64)…
respringRootListController.m:20:40: error: 'UIApplication' may not respond to 'reboot' [-Werror]
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] reboot];
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
1 error generated.
make[3]: *** [/Users/valentincocq/respringx/.theos/obj/debug/arm64/respringRootListController.m.5460b32b.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/Users/valentincocq/respringx/.theos/obj/debug/arm64/RespringX.bundle/RespringX] Error 2
make[1]: *** [internal-bundle-all_] Error 2
make: *** [RespringX.all.bundle.variables] Error 2
MacBook-Pro-de-Valentin:respringx valentincocq$`

**I have try this, but don't work too :**

`-(void)reboot {
    system("reboot");
}`

**Thank for you help.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Theos iOS 11 system() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53922933/theos-ios-11-system-function)

Comment: So, system command work good for me it’s just the reboot argument who is a problem because don’t work